# Make Spring-Security oauth services transactional

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, transactions

I have developed a OAuth provider based on Spring-Security OAuth Project (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/).
I did need persist token information into a database, then I implement a new `TokenStore` using MyBatis (my persistence framework).

The problem now is that the persistence of the token is not transactional, the same happens if you use the (out of the box) component `JdbcTokenStore` provided by Spring.

Where should I put the transactional control? Should I apply the transactional control on `tokenServices` service (`DefaultTokenServices` class) or endpoint (`/oauth/token`)?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add a aspect directly on DefaultTokenServices to give it the transactional behavior, and thus each call to methods of this class are transactional.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
     <tx:attributes> 
        <tx:method name="get*, is*, read*" read-only="true"/> 
        <tx:method name="*"/> 
     </tx:attributes> 
</tx:advice> 
<aop:config> 
    <aop:pointcut id="tokenServicesPointcut" expression="bean(tokenServices)"/> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="tokenServicesPointcut"/> 
 </aop:config>
```